# Обработка событии клавиатуры JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, jni

При создании `JavaFX` приложения можно задать вот такую функцию главному окну (`primayStage`, или другому объекту `Node`):

```
primaryStage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("key pressed");
    }
});

//При нажатии любой кнопки выводит "key pressed".
```

Но что действует пока в фокусе наша приложение. Чтобы получать всегда событии клавиатуры я нашёл библиотеку `JNA API` ( Porject Kenai), в которой есть такой класс:

```
KeyboardUtils keyb = new KeyboardUtils();

while(true){
    if (keyb.isPressed(65)) {
        System.out.println("Pressed A");
        break;
    }
}

//При нажатии на А выводит "Pressed A".
```

**Внимание, вопрос: Как мне сделать, чтобы получало всегда события клавиатуры (даже когда не находится в фокусе)?**

Пожалуйста, дайте хоть малейшую зацепку!

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить, а зачем вам вообще нужно обрабатывать события с клавиатуры, если они никак не связаны с приложением?

Comment: Когда пользователь выделяет текс (на каком-то саите на пример) и нажимает CTRL+C моё приложение должно выводить окошко с параметрами форматирование текста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете получать информацию из буфера обмена:

```
String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

Вот пример таймера:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20),
    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);   
timeline.play();
```

Comment: Моё приложение должно облегчить копи - пасте -> выбрал текст -> нажал CTRL+C -> около выборного текста появляется окошко для форматирование текста -> нажимаем Insert -> текст отправляется в  .txt или .docx.
Проблема не в извлечение из буфера, а в постоянном проверке событии клавиатуры.

Comment: @Igor Onofrei, по поводу постоянной проверки событий клавиатуры, то можно (например, по таймеру) проверять изменения в буфере обмена.

Comment: Можно реализовать интерфейс ClipboardOwner и lostOwnership(), и с их помощью пытаться отслеживать событие записи в буфер обмена.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста как это сделать. (я про таимер)

Comment: @Igor Onofrei, я добавил в ответ код таймера. Вы можете запустить таймер и проверять в нём не изменился ли буфер обмена. Я не уверен, что это самый лучший способ, но более-менее простой.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартными средствами java это не возможно, так как java выполняется в JVM, вы не можете слушать глобальные события системы.

Для этой задачи необходимо воспользоваться следующей библиотекой:
https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook

Данная нативная библиотека позволяет решить данную проблему